# What happens when a database operation in indexedDB is successful, but the transaction fails immediately

Tags: javascript, callback, indexeddb

I have a DB operation which stores value into an indexed DB. I am in search of an answer to a situation where my operation succeeds. That is I store my values in the DB successfully. But upon storing, if the transaction fails immediately, what happens to the stored data?

Also, if the transaction fails, will the transaction.complete() execute or transaction.onerror() execute?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please **edit the question**  to include the code and add the appropriate tags to your question so we know what database you are using.

Comment: If a [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) fails, it means that nothing will have happened to the stored data. (I.e. the changes either were never recorded in the first place, or they are automatically rolled back). That's exactly what transactions are good for.

Answer (score 2):

Your statements conflict. Nevertheless the basics are:

- A transaction provides a period of time in which you can execute requests
- A transaction can provide multiple requests
- Any individual request success does not mean a transaction was successful
- Any individual request failure generally means a transaction will be unsuccessful
- A transaction is a buffer, in between your requests and the database, where although requests may complete, the database is not actually modified until the transaction completes
- Side note that this is made very slightly confusing by the fact that some indexedDB implementations will report a transaction as successful prematurely (before the IO operation of writing the data to storage actually completes).

Let's suppose you have a transaction with two operations (requests). Let's say the first request completes. Has the data been stored? No. Let's say the second request completes. Has the data been stored yet? No.
Then the transaction completes. Has the data been stored yet? Yes.

If there is a problem storing the data, the transaction will fail (except for the minor technicality regarding how some implementations 'lie' about flushing to disk prematurely).

If a transaction fails, the database is left in its state prior to the transaction starting, ignoring concurrent transactions.

If a request fails, then the transaction eventually fails, and as was just stated, the database is left in its state prior to the transaction starting. All requests that are a part of the same failed transaction are rolled back.

Think of this kind of like opening a document in your favorite text editor, typing some words, then closing the document without saving.

The complete event is fired when the transaction completes successfully. The error event is fired when the transaction does not complete successfully.

Comment: Thanks @Josh for the answer